# How to get the current plugin directory in Wordpress in javascript file?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am new in wordpress, doing a plug in for word press site. Here is a problem with me, i want to get plug in url with my plug in name dynamically in javascript file.
Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) gives you the ability to write a javaScript object with multiple variables defined. Like :

```
<?php wp_localize_script('some_handle', 'object_name', array( 'plugin_url' => plugins_url() )); ?>
```